# Comparing custom linear regression solver to SciPy equivalent in Python

Tags: python, scipy, regression

From a given data set, I set out to complete a task which is below

> 5. Fit the data of the previous exercise to fit Eq. (8.18) using the SciPy function `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()`. Plot the data as symbols and the fit as a line on linear and on log-log axes in two separate plots in the same figure window. Compare your results to those of the previous exercise.

Here is the data I had.

[image]

I attempted the problem with the following Python script.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(K, t, p):
    return (K * np.power(t, p))

def func1(c, m, x):
    return (m * x + c)

def LineFitWt(x, y, dy):
    """Fit to straight line.
    Inputs: x, y, and dy (y-uncertainty) arrays.
    Ouputs: slope and y-intercept of best fit to data.
    """
    dy2 = dy ** 2
    norm = (1. / dy2).sum()
    xhat = (x / dy2).sum() / norm
    yhat = (y / dy2).sum() / norm
    slope = ((x - xhat) * y / dy2).sum() / ((x - xhat) * x / dy2).sum()
    yint = yhat - slope * xhat
    dy2_slope = 1. / ((x - xhat) * x / dy2).sum()
    dy2_yint = dy2_slope * (x * x / dy2).sum() / norm
    return slope, yint, np.sqrt(dy2_slope), np.sqrt(dy2_yint)


def redchisq(x, y, dy, slope, yint):
    chisq = (((y - yint - slope * x) / dy) ** 2).sum()
    return chisq / float(x.size - 2)

# Extract data from the text file for t, s and ds
t, s, ds = np.loadtxt("growthdata.txt", skiprows=3, unpack=True)

print ("time =", t)
print("size = ", s)
print ("Uncertainty =", ds)

# Set X and Y for the relevant axis
X = np.log(t)
Y = np.log(s)
dY = np.log(ds)

# Call LineFitWt function to calculate the gradient(m), y-intercept(c) and uncertainties in these(dm, dc)
m, c, dm, dc = LineFitWt(X, Y, dY)
rchisq = redchisq(X, Y, dY, m, c)
SciPy_Fit = curve_fit(func, t, s, p0=([0.54, 5.83]))

# Assign values for scipy fit
p_s = SciPy_Fit[0][0]
K_s = np.exp(SciPy_Fit[0][1])

# Calculate straight line properties for scipy parameters
m_s = p_s
c_s = np.log(K_s)

print ("m = ", m)
print ("c = ", c)
print ("dm = ",dm)
print ("dc = ", dc)  
print ("Reduced chi square = ", rchisq)
print ("SciPy_Fit values  = ", SciPy_Fit)
print ("SciPy Fit p = ", p_s)
print ("SciPy Fit K = ", K_s)

# Calculate the values for p and K
p = m
K = np.exp(c)

print ("p = ", p)
print ("K = ", K)

# Calculate values for custom fit points (y = mx + c)
Xext = 0.05*(X.max()-X.min())
Xfit = (np.array([X.min()-Xext, X.max()+Xext]))
Yfit= (c+m*Xfit)

# Calculate points for log log graph using Custom fit
Y_custom = func(K, t, p)

# Calculate values for SciPy y = mx + c fit
X_scipy = X
Y_scipy = (m_s * X + c_s)    

# Calculate values for log-log plot using SciPy parameters
Y_scipy_loglog = func(K_s, t, p_s)

# Assign a figure object to plot on. 
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(X, Y,"x", label="Data")
plt.errorbar(X, Y, yerr=dY, zorder=-1, label="Unc in s")
plt.plot(Xfit, Yfit,"+--", label="Custom Fit")
plt.plot(X_scipy, Y_scipy, "D--", label="SciPy Fit")
plt.text(-1, -2, 'Custom fit m={0:0.4f}, c={1:0.4f}'.format(m,c))
plt.text(-1, -5, 'SciPy Fit m={0:0.4f}, c={1:0.4f}'.format(m_s,c_s))
plt.xlabel("ln s")
plt.ylabel("ln r")
plt.legend()
plt.plot()

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.loglog(t, s, "x", label="Data")
plt.errorbar(t, s, yerr=ds, label="Uncertainty in s", zorder=-1)
plt.loglog(t, Y_custom, "--", label="Custom fit")
plt.loglog(t, Y_scipy_loglog, "D--", label="SciPy Fit")
plt.xlabel("t")
plt.ylabel("s")
plt.text(0.1, 1, 'Custom fit K={0:0.4f}, p={1:0.4f}'.format(K, p))
plt.text(0.1, 10, 'SciPy Fit K={0:0.4f}, p={1:0.4f}'.format(K_s, p_s))
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I then obtained the following graphs[image: Matplotlib plots]

Here are the printed outputs.

```
time = [ 0.12  0.18  0.42  0.9   2.1   6.   18.   42.  ]
size =  [ 115.  130.  202.  335.  510.  890. 1700. 2600.]
Uncertainty = [10. 12. 14. 18. 20. 30. 40. 50.]
m =  0.5419106669494728
c =  5.837596806432137
dm =  0.5518341454711854
dc =  1.0280703524098318
Reduced chi square =  0.0002705479986781181
SciPy_Fit values  =  (array([  0.67373601, -10.71638416]), array([[-3.48433902e+11,  1.40195650e+13], [ 1.40195650e+13, -5.64090353e+14]]))
SciPy Fit p =  0.6737360069383264
SciPy Fit K =  2.217856767946089e-05
p =  0.5419106669494728
K =  342.9541642911326
```

What am I missing here? Why is the SciPy fit so far from the data and the custom fit?

Comment: What you do you mean by "missing something"?

Comment: As in, have I made some sort of glaring mistake? My initial parameters? or the function itself. Just at a loss really. My only conclusion is that the SciPy function isn't suitable or the assumpution that the function chosen isn't a good fit.

Comment: We all guessed that you made a mistake but that's not helping people help you. Right now your question can be summarize as "Can somebody debug my code for me?", but that's not how this site work.

Comment: I know I wanted to test my fundamental assumptions first with more experienced people such as yourselves. If you put the likelihood of a debugging error ill work on that. Thanks!